# Javascript: encapsulating state, exposing behaviour

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming, encapsulation

I'm trying to improve my Javascript fundamentals so I can explore client-side frameworks (Knockout, Angular etc) and make progress in learning Node.js.

I've taken a simple problem which I use in teaching C# and I'm trying to solve it with Javascript.

> ### The Problem
>
> Create probability objects with an internal value for percentage of likelihood. For example, a 2/5 probability would be created with:

```
var firstOne = new Probability(40); // 2/5 is a 40% chance
```

> That internal state should not be accessible through the instance variable. The purpose of the Probability function/object is to encapsulate the ability to compare one against another:

```
var secondOne = new Probability(30);
var areTheyEqual = firstOne.SameAs(secondOne); // returns false in this example
```

In C# this is relatively straight forward. The value of probability is stored in a member variable with private scope, and the SameAs function is public scope. Because each instance uses the same type, Probability, C#'s scoping allows the calling member to also 'see' the passed member's private state:

```
// C#
public class Probability
{
    private int _value;

    public Probability(int percent)
    {
        _value = percent;
    }

    public bool SameAs(Probability other)
    {
        return this._value == other._value; // works even though _value is private
    }
}
```

I wondered if this kind of encapsulation could be achieved with Javascript. As a secondary question, perhaps what I'm trying to do is driven from a C# and OO perspective, where Javascript may offer alternative approaches to solve the problem that take advantage of Javascript's functional abilities. I'm open to both types of response.

Comment: No. JavaScript does not use class-scoped visibility modifiers. Typically you'd just make them (public) properties and do not use any privateness at all. It is *possible* to achieve, yes, but not practical.

Answer (score 0):

You can work JavaScript closures to get close to what you're use to in other object oriented languages, e.g. something like:

```
function Probability() {
// private field
    var _value = 0;
    this.getValue = function() {
        return _value;
    };

    this.setValue = function(newValue) {
       _value = newValue;
    };

    this.sameAs = function(compare) {
        return _value === compare.getValue();
    };
}

var probability = new Probability();
probability.setValue(10);

var newProbability= new Probability();
newProbability.setValue(11);

console.log(probability.sameAs(newProbability)); // false
newProbability.setValue(10);
console.log(probability.sameAs(newProbability)); // true
```

You can find a lot of referencess when googling for Object-oriented JavaScript, I can recommend [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to encapsulate the internal state so that it's not accessible (for set or get) from outside. In my C# example, it's not possible to read the internal value of an instance of Probability, all you can do is compare against another.